# How can i get a batch file to copy a .lnk shortcut to the desktop

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

When i try to move the file I get an error message that the file cannot be found, I did notice that the shortcut file does not append .lnk in the folder view even though i have "hide known extensions" unselected.

also the cmd.exe dir command shows the file exactly as written.

if i add the .lnk to the windows explorer file, i get .lnk.lnk and i still get file not found

```
IF NOT EXIST "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Remote Service Restarter.lnk" (
echo f | xcopy /f /y "Remote Service Restarter.lnk" "%DESKTOP%\Remote Service Restarter.lnk"
) ELSE (
del "Remote Service Restarter.lnk"
echo removing redundant installer file
)
```

any ideas?

Comment: Im calling the batch file from the same directory as the lnk file, it should always be deployed with the lnk in the same folder.

other moves for other types of files work, along with the IF NOT EXIST logic working, but not this shortcut

Comment: Can you try '%USERPROFILE%\Desktop' instead of '%DESKTOP%' on the second line or is there folder redirection involved here? (what does echo %DESKTOP% give you?)

Comment: yeah i did try it with the userprofile.... 
 and theres a redirect, the desktop that is actually displayed is the onedrive backup, the real desktop under userprofile has 1 file in it... the link ive been trying to move.

if you make your suggestion an answer i can mark it solved, i can work out the directory tree from the echo output of %userprofile%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try '%USERPROFILE%\Desktop' instead of '%DESKTOP%' on the second line?

Is there folder redirection involved here? (what does echo %DESKTOP% give you?)

You may need to access from %USERPROFILE% if there is

Comment: it turns out there is a redirect on the %USERPROFILE% that does not point to the desktop and %DESKTOP% does not provide a response.

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 locations for the Desktop path. One is the `per user` desktop folder, and the other is the `all users` desktop folder.

It is likely that the file is located in the other folder, thus you see the file on your desktop, but your batchfile can't actually find it.

The locations are:

- `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop`
- `%PUBLIC%\Desktop`

Also, keep in mind, %DESKTOP% is not an environmental value that exists by default and will not be present on most systems. It may actually not exist on your own system either. Using the 2 paths above is guaranteed to work on any system from Windows XP and up.

Comment: sorry i was trying that other variable, but it doesnt work for either variable, in any combination